# Need to learn BitCoin (for Beginner)

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm new to bit coin and can anyone provide a website, e books or anything to learn from the basic step?
Appreciate any reply.

Comment: Google?  Seriously, just google "bitcoin howto" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the best reads for beginners: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6jlop4/rbitcoin_faq_newcomers_please_read/

Answer (score 0):

Andreas Antanopolous' [Mastering Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook) is probably the best resource, especially from a technical standpoint.